# Mettere i soldi dove si mettono le parole

Tags: phrase-request

Buongiorno,

Cosa significa "mettere i soldi dove si mettono le parole"? Penso sia l'equivalente dell'inglese "put your money where your mouth is" ma non so se sia così e non ne conosco il significato. Qualcuno qui lo sa e lo può spiegare?

Grazie.

Comment: Non conoscevo l'espressione inglese, ma da quel che ho letto, l'equivalente in italiano dovrebbe essere "passare dalle parole ai fatti".  "Mettere i soldi dove si mettono le parole" mi sembra una traduzione letterale, che non rende il senso del modo di dire.

Comment: A me sembra una semplice traduzione letterale del modo di dire inglese. Non credo di averlo mai sentito in italiano.

Comment: [Qui](http://www.ilmioinglese.com/2011/05/24/espressioni-idiomatiche-in-inglese-che-contengono-la-parola-mouth-bocca/) appare come un modo di dire inglese, ma non italiano.

Comment: Forse dovresti riformulare la tua domanda.

Comment: Visto così, sembra un goffo calco dall'inglese. Dove l'hai letto (in italiano)?

Comment: Una frase senza senso, probabilmente una brutta copia di un modo di dire inglese.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nonostante **“mettere i soldi dove si mettono le parole”**, in Italiano, non sia un’espressione usata, se l’hai sentita da qualcuno, è da intendere ovviamente con lo stesso significato di **“put your money where your mouth is”**, ovvero dare peso alle proprie parole.
In Italiano diciamo **“passare dalle parole ai fatti”** che è lo stesso concetto di “put your money where your mouth is” e “mettere i soldi dove si mettono le parole”.